# Generate Active Admin Comment during a Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin

How can I use Ruby/Rails code to generate an `ActiveAdmin` comment - such as during a controller action, or in an `ActiveRecord` lifecycle callback? (For example, when I change the status of a `Order` record from 'closed' to 'open'.)

Comment: did you get it working?

Comment: Hello Andrey, I have one little question regarding the author_id method. If I want to assign it to a current admin user. How is that possible? I tried it this way  author_id: AdminUser.current_admin_user.id,  but it doesn't work.  What should I do?

Comment: `author_id: current_admin_user.id`

Comment: I have this error : undefined local variable or method `current_admin_user' for my model.   i tried with try method to make it work , then i hit this following error author_id, author_type. then i put this 2 params on attr_accesible and still error i encounter.

Comment: You do not have access to such methods in model. In model you have to pass id of the user. So if you call the method, defined in model, you can pass the id. hange method definition to `add_comment(admin_id)` in model, and when you call the method from controller or view, `add_comment(current_admin_user.id)`

Comment: got it? let me know if any further help needed

Comment: I got it. I'll try to fix it and let you know how it went and thank you a lot.

Comment: I added a little tweaks.  author_id: PaperTrail.whodunnit.try(:id)  for the method and i added the parameters authod_id and author_type on the comments.rb file from config/initializers from AA and now is working. Thanks a lot for helping me .

Comment: I really appreciate this question and this answer, and I've been trying to figure out edits so it'll pass the other mod's "focused" requirements. Maybe this time! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let say you have a `User` model, and you want to create a comment to a particular user.

in model:

```
after_update :add_comment

 def add_comment 
  ActiveAdmin::Comment.create(
    resource_id: User.last.id, # id of that particular user to which you add comment
    namespace: 'admin',
    body: 'Your comment body',
    resource_type: 'User',
    author_id: 1, # id of the comment's author, could be AdminUser.first, for example
    author_type: 'AdminUser'
  )
end
```